# I got a weird message in the console when running my java project

Tags: java, javafx

When I run my project in  NetBeans I receive this message in the console.

> Launching  task from C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre..\lib\ant-javafx.jar Warning: From
>   JDK7u25 the Codebase manifest attribute should be used to restrict JAR
>   repurposing.
>            Please set manifest.custom.codebase property to override the current default non-secure value '*'. Launching  task from
>   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre..\lib\ant-javafx.jar No base
>   JDK. Package will use system JRE. No base JDK. Package will use system
>   JRE.

My project seems to run fine but I want to know if it is anything to worry about.

Comment: It looks like the paths to your JDK and JRE might be set up wrong. Check the paths in NetBeans, and the PATH. NetBeans might be defaulting on its own version if it can't find yours... or something.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/javafx_ant_tasks.html) you need to have a `JAVA_HOME` property in your `build.xml` file pointing to your JDK:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<project name="JavaFX Hello World Example" default="default" basedir="."
  xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">

  <property name="JAVA_HOME" value="C:\\Java\\jdk1.8.0"/>
```